# Sortable Containment between rows and columns of a container

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-draggable

How to restrict sortable to be to allow only columns inside a rows and rows inside a container?

**Example:**

Container is having rows and columns. Both rows and columns are sortable. But  how to stop row inserted inside a columns?

[Working Link](http://www.layoutit.com/build)

```
$(".demo, .demo .column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    opacity: .35,
    handle: ".drag"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

I splitted the connectWith as below.

```
$(".demo ").sortable({
    connectWith: ".demo",
    opacity: .35,
    handle: ".drag"
});

$(".demo .column").sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    opacity: .35,
    handle: ".drag"
});
```